# Realloc fails in loop

Tags: c, pointers

I want to read a number as an array of int, but something strange happens.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getNumber( int ** dst )
{
    int size = 0;
    int num = 0;

    scanf( "%c", &num );
    while( num != 10 )
    {
        if( (num < 48) || (num > 57) )
        {
            printf( "This is not a number.\r\n" );
            return -1;
        }
        size++;

        *dst = ( int * ) realloc( *dst, sizeof( int ) * size );
        *dst[ size - 1 ] = ( num - 48 );

        scanf( "%c", &num );
    }

    return size;
}

int main()
{
    int * number = NULL;
    int size = 0;

    size = getNumber( &number );

    return 0;
}
```

First iteration passes normally, but on the second iteration `*dst[ size - 1 ] = ( num - 48 );` fails.
What is wrong?

Comment: "Fails" means what? Crash, produces wrong output, draws a duck on the screen?

Comment: @MatsPetersson It throws "Access violation". I've fixed it.

Comment: Yes, my point was that you should describe what actually happens when it goes wrong, not just "it doesn't work".

Comment: If I were you, I would use %d instead of %c with the scanf. You are reading an integer.

Comment: You should really not use magic numbers. Either use `ctpyes.h` (`isdigit()`), or compare with the char literals `'0'`/`'9'`. That makes things much more readable and maintainable. (two months from now, you start wondering what `48` and `57` actually mean).

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast the results of `malloc()`, `realloc()` & friends!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I found it!
The problem was in the feature of handling dereferencing operators.
Square brackets have a higher priority than asterisk.
Because of it, if I modify that line:
`*dst[ size - 1 ] = ( num - 48 );`
Like that:
`(*dst)[ size - 1 ] = ( num - 48 );`
It will work properly!

Comment: You can avoid this problem by passing the pointer by reference, `int &*dst` instead of `int **dst` [of course, you then need to remove some `*` and `&` in all relevant places]

Comment: @MatsPetersson I knew it, but I use C, not C++.

Answer (score 2):

because [ ] has higher precedence than * operator.so it behaves like `*(dst[size-1])`
 instead of `(*dst)[size-1]`.